Lighting only bakes to a part of mesh
I'm trying to bake lighting onto this mesh (this is the first time ive baked something for the record)

When I try to bake the lights onto the mesh, it only bakes on the feet.

I'm not sure why this is happening, my shading tab looks fine,

and my uvs are unwrapped.
I've tried a couple things that didn't work:

I've tried ticking off direct lighting in the bake menu,
I've tried switching from combined bake type to diffuse,
I've tried using a Principled BSDF instead of a non-principled BSDF, (gotten from here)
I have every vertex selected on my mesh, and I am selecting the image node in the shader tab when baking

any help is appreciated!! im very confused!!


Check if there are hidden or disabled in viewports objects in the scene. Press Alt + H.
Check the orientation of the mesh normals. Use the viewport overlay.


Yes, it ldoes ook as if there might be some kind of cube that's been hidden in the viewport that could explain the shape of the shadow in the bake.

That was it! Apparently I had a couple objects that were hidden in scene view but not render. thanks!
